# How to edit a model that is saved in project?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I have a model saved in QGIS Project which i can find under "Project models". But how can I open and edit it?

I have tried dragging and dropping it to the empty canvas, and using open Icon in toolbar (only .model3 files can be opened there), double clicking (runs the model), right clicking etc.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it.. Go to Processing menu- Toolbox - Project models - right click and Edit model: (This does not seem to work though for a Project saved in QGIS 3.10 that is opened in 3.12, have to save as model3-file in 3.10 then open file in 3.12):

[image]